# Count occurrence of distinct substring in Python

Tags: python, distinct

I want to find the occurrence of distinct substring in the string with Python. Any suggestions?

The dataset is

```
Fruit                     
apple|pear|grape|apple      
pear|pear|apple|apple
```

I want to count the distinct kind of fruit. The result I want is:

```
Fruit                   Num_Fruit
------------------------------------
apple|pear|grape|apple       3
====================================
pear|pear|apple|apple        2
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can't expect us to do your homework for you

Comment: Any attempt of your own that you'd like to share?

Answer (score 0):

One go at it.

```
data = """
apple|pear|grape|apple
pear|pear|apple|apple
""".strip()

merged = [x.split("|") for x in data.split("\n")]

for row in merged:
  temp_val = ["|".join(row), str(len(set(row)))]
  print("|".join(temp_val))


apple|pear|grape|apple|3
pear|pear|apple|apple|2
```

Comment: Can you explain it more? Thanks!

Comment: data is a large string. It contains new lines and pipe characters. to create a list of your entries, you first split on the new line, then on the pipe, gives you a nested list of 2 dimensions. Then loop over it, then create a string of the list's items and add a string containing the length of the row to the end.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open("test.txt")   #has the dataset
lines=f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    unique=[]           #store unique fruits
    line=line.rstrip()  #remove "\n"
    line=line.replace(" ",'')  #remove extra spaces
    fruits=line.split('|')  #split by delimiter 
    print(line,len(set(fruits)))
```

One way to do it is using set data structure.